# New install of ubuntu 22.04.1LTS new machine, no desktop folder in files, only home & has everything on desktop there

Tags: unity

I have since my last post got a new machine: Asus520M-Plus
16GiB Mem
AMD® Ryzen 5 5600 6-core processor × 12
NV167 Graphics
1.5 TB Disk
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
64-bit
Gnome ver42.4
Wayland
Also got an Asus ProArt 27 Wide Screen Display.
It had Ubuntu installed via an authenticated download on a flash drive. My problem after starting to copy files to the new machine is that dropping stuff on to the desktop, to sort as I went, I discovered that there is no desktop folder within the files icon on the left of the screen. If I I click that icon it is automatically 'home', and has everything that is on screen contained within.
I did not do anything to the machine during install and need help to get this sorted. I dont want to carry on until it is as it will only be storing problems up for the future. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are missing default folders you have a corrupted install. Are you maybe running a server install?

Comment: You added the tag "Unity". Are you using the Unity desktop? If not, correct your tags.

Comment: Hi David, clicking on files, documents, music, pictures,videos, and downloads gives msg "Oops something went wrong. Unable to find /home/bob/desktop/folder name please check spelling etc...It was a standard install as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Vanadium No I'm not using unity, but was unable to post my question with a multitude of other tags even suggested ones as I don't have the privileges yet. Sorry to be a pain!